# Align top of text EXACTLY with top border of container

Tags: css

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a7fatxm/) looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this (I created this with MS Paint)... flush:

[image]

Is there anything I can add to the styles to achieve this?

```
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 50px; // this number should be treated as arbitrary
}
```

Comment: Using the line-height would be one option http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cf507z9L/

Comment: Since CSS doesn't know about font metrics other than the height of the x, the width of the — and the width of the 0, there is no real CSS-only solution. Workarounds are below, but take note that they use values based on manual measurements of the letter height, which is different for different fonts.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). The amount will depend on the font-family you are using. The advantage would be that `line-height` can directly depend on font-size so it can be dynamic. However, it doesn't have a concept of vertical top and bottom individually (it applies to both) so you won't have that space under the text.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Times';
  line-height: 0.7; /* This will work for any font-size on 'Times'*/
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

You could simulate that bottom space by wrapping the text in an element with margin-bottom.

```css
div.outer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 70px;
}

div.inner {
  font-family: 'Times';
  line-height: 0.7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use relative positioning. An advantage of this method over line-height is that the div size does not change.

```css
div {
  border:1px solid blue;
  font-size: 64px; // works for arbitrary font sizes
}
span{
   position:relative; 
   top:-0.21em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

As with line-height, you might have to adjust "-0.21em" depending on your font. -0.21em worked well for me for sans-serif and serif, but not cursive.